# Are the privileges pages common to across sites?

Tags: support, edits, privileges

I was thinking of adding a note to https://meta.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools about not deleting questions closed as duplicates which is applicable across all sites. If I edit one page will that change get duplicated across all sites or not?

I don't want to cut and paste the edit lots of times plus I don't have rights to edit that page on all sites.

The change is something along the lines of:

> It's a good idea to keep questions closed as duplicates on the site. They provide additional routes to the answer. Think long and hard before voting to delete.

Comment: Gah, just went to edit and found that Shog9 had beaten me to it - by several days! Must have skimmed over that bit when reading the page last night. At least the question was useful to establish the facts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now the intent is for the priv wikis to be default text across sites so:

- don't add anything specific to meta.so
- make sure what you do add, works as generalized advice for every site in the network

Comment: I'll have a further think about the wording to make sure it's clear.

Comment: Am I missing something? Does editing one edit them all?

Comment: @tshepang meta.so privilege wikis are the "master" copies and are periodically pushed out to the rest of the network