# What are the limits with edits to questions?

Tags: discussion, comments, edits

### Intro

I understand the basic idea of the question editing functions, both the person asking and the person reading or answering's perspective. From my understanding:

**Person asking do edits because:**

- It is to clarify what they mean in their question (could be a term, phrase, example, etc.)
- They have been asked a question in the comments, such as being asked for more detail.
- A spelling or grammar error.
- An example error they notice after some more time spent trying to figure it out on their own.
- An update for things such as the above (with or without mentioning that it is an update).
- Other.

**Person reading, commenting or answering do edits because:**

- It is to clarify what they assume the person is asking.
- There is unnecessary text included.
- A spelling or grammar error.
- Change the title to make it so others who may ask similar questions be able to find it easier.
- Change the tags for the same reason as above.

### What are the limits with edits to questions?

As I explained above, there are multiple, understandable reasons for why we currently do edits. However, I came across some experiences where an edit had taken a (most likely) unexpected result.

It was when I commented on the question to ask what software the person asking was using. I know for most of these Stack Exchanges, the tags include the software title within the theme to be more detailed, but that question did not include one which was the reason I asked. The next thing I know, someone mentions me in a new comment and asks me why I "don't check the tags". I checked the edits and it showed it was done after I had asked the question.

In other cases, I'm the one questioning whether I should edit my own question, or not, or reply in the comment that I did make an edit. No matter what changes are made, unless they are grammar or spelling errors, most edits will have some effect on people who start reading *after* the edit has been made. Some examples would be:

- The one I mentioned previously: Adding a tag that previously was not included. It would most likely lead to things such as confusion, like "Why is that other person asking what software they're using when it's mentioned in the tags?"
- An update to the problem-solving, but still not at the answer: Maybe half of their question is answered already just from what they updated, but that updated data is also needed in order to solve the rest of the problem.

Would there be a better way to link the answer with the edited question? Would it be better if the original questioner only comments on the answer to a question from a helper?

Comment: I don't know, I would say that if people are bullying you because they can't be bothered to read that you asked the question before the edit, I would say the problem is not you. Flag it. (And then delete your comment if your question has been answered, from an edit or otherwise, of course. At which point the flag could be for rude or no longer necessary.)

Comment: `There is unnecessary text included.` -> like "Intro"? :-)

Comment: @Stuckat1337 I did not mean bully, I meant more like if we should filter our edit changes, and if so how?

Comment: _I_ take that as bullying. They shouldn't be harassing you because they _assumed_ you asked your question without looking at the tags. They're guilty of doing a very similar thing.

Comment: Anyway `"Why is that other person asking what software they're using when it's mentioned in the tags?"` -> flag those comments as obsolete ("It's no longer needed"). And don't worry about people who see it and raise an eyebrow in the meantime. The psychology around _comments_ is really low priority because they are only supposed to be used to help readers and/or improve the question. Questions that challenge why someone else asked a comment are like 12th class citizens and should be blown away.

Comment: I guess my question may be misunderstood. I don't mean for it to sound like a complaint, though I agree it's unnecessary for others to be unfriendly to those trying to help. I asked the question of what should be kept in mind when editing questions.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11476/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74430/282094

Answer (score 3):

When you are looking at:

> An update to the problem-solving, but still not at the answer: Maybe
> half of their question is answered already just from what they
> updated, but that updated data is also needed in order to solve the
> rest of the problem.

I would suggest that you are trying to use an SE site for a technical discussion, or multiple questions in one, rather than the focused Q&A it is designed for.

If you need to ask a follow-up question, which is more than using a comment to clarify the answer, after receiving an answer to your original one, then I think that should be done as a new question.